# PrimeNg + JHipster : insert jhitranslation in growl messages

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster, primeng

I'm a beginner and working on an app built with JHipster, using Angular 4.3 and Prime NG.

My problem is that I would like to use my translations files (json files) in prime ng components. But only string messages work...

My code looks like this :

```
import {Message} from 'primeng/components/common/api';

export class MyComp implements OnInit {
    msgs: Message[] = [];

    callError() {
        this.msgs = [];
        this.msgs.push({severity: 'error',
            summary: 'Error',
            detail: 'error.errorOccured' // doesn't find the translation file = displays 'error.errorOccured'
            detail: 'An error occured, please contact your administrator.' // works
        });
    }
}
```

In all other ts files, I call the translation files like this : `'error.errorOccured'`.

I see that I push json in the messages, but I don't know how to insert a json translation and not a string.

My Json file :

```
{
    "error": {
        "errorOccured": "An error occured, please contact your administrator."
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to access the JSON key from component ts file, it was for jhiTranslate directive in HTML file

I had the similar problem when using PrimeNG file upload. It was hard to translate upload labels. My dirty solution is using `JhiLanguageService` checks `currentLang` and then return hardcoded sentences. In my case it occurred only in one place so it was easy to modify. If you need to apply it in multiple places you can wrap them into a Utility class.

```
 constructor(private languageService: JhiLanguageService) {}

  private getLabel(english, spanish){
    if (this.languageService.currentLang === 'en') {
      return english;
    }
    return spanish;
  }

  onChooseLabel() {
    return this.getLabel('Choose', 'Escoger Archivo');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use jhipster internationalization wiht growl components

first add required modules in shared-libs.module.ts

```
import { GrowlModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        GrowlModule
    ],
    exports: [
        ...
        GrowlModule
    ]
})
export class AppSharedLibsModule {}
```

then use the TranslationService in your component to load messages

myEntity-update.component.ts

```
import { Message } from 'primeng/api';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
export class MyEntityUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    msgs: Message[] = [];

    constructor(
        ...
        private translateService: TranslateService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        ...        this.translateService.get('myApp.myEntity.errors.summary').subscribe(summaryTranslated => {
            this.msgs.push({severity: 'success', summary: summaryTranslated, detail: 'Via MessageService'});
        });
    }
}
```

assuming you have the translation in your json language files in the folder i18n, in example

src/main/webapp/i18n/en/myEntity.json

```
{
    "myApp": {
        "myEntity" : {
            ...
            "errors": {
                "summary": "Something went wrong, try again later."
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Also see: [primeng file upload angular i18n internationalization](https://wordpress.com/post/cirovladimir.wordpress.com/3682)

jhipster version: 5.4.2, primeNG version: 6.1.4